# Pandasで行の削除をしたい

Tags: python, pandas

以下のようなデータをPandasで扱っており、A列が連番になるように行を削除したいです。
（2-13行目、15-21行目を削除してA列の数字が1,2...になるようにしたいです。）
良い方法があればご教示くださいませんか？

**対象のデータ:**

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
1   1   0   0   0   4   1163.7
2   1   0.8 0.8 2.2 0   0
3   1   0.2 0.2 4.4 0   0
4   1   0.8 0.4 0.4 0   0
5   1   0.5 0.7 3.8 0   0
6   1   1   1   8.9 0   0
7   1   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
8   1   2   2   8.7 0   0
9   1   3   3   5.  0   0
10  1   4.5 4.5 2.2 0   0
11  1   6.0 6.5 0.8 0   0
12  1   8   8   0.3 0   0
13  1   5.3 0   0   1   116
14  2   0   0   0   4   116
15  2   0.8 0.8 1.1 0   0
16  2   0.2 0.5 3.4 0   0
17  2   0.4 0.8 3.2 0   0
18  2   0.7 0.5 3.0 0   0
19  2   1   1   1.5 0   0
20  2   1.5 1.5 1.7 0   0
21  2   2   2   7.9 0   0
・
・
・
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drop_duplicates()`というメソッドがあります。
これらの記事を参照。
[pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)
[PandasのDataFrameやSeriesで重複要素を取り除く方法](https://qiita.com/kira4845/items/6798e54eb76b15329e3c)
[pandas.DataFrame, Seriesの重複した行を抽出・削除](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-duplicated-drop-duplicates/)

質問のDataFrameが`df`に入っているものとして、以下のようにすれば出来るでしょう。
ただし、これを呼び出す時点で`A`列は重複有無にかかわらず昇順になっている必要があります。

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='A', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```